# React native credit card input

Tags: react-native, expo, credit-card

Can anyone recommend a good library for react native - expo that manages credit card inputs? I tried using `react-native-credit-card-input` but the project looks dead and it has many deprecated hooks and dependencies.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can check this site see what package is better then another

https://www.npmtrends.com/react-native-awesome-card-io-vs-react-native-credit-card-vs-react-native-credit-card-input

but the package that you motioned is not deprecated and that's a good one

Comment: It uses methods like componentDidMount(), componentWillRecieveProps(), etc. which are considered deprecated by react.

Comment: yeah that's true but ignore that for now until the new update